# Negative Binary Convertion

Tags: binary

How do I go about converting -2 decimal to two's compliment in 7 bits? I know in 8 bit representation -2 is 11111110 but for 7 bit I am confused?

Comment: This is more a question for [so] or for [cs.SE], I would think.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same number, but one less $1$.

Comment: so would it be 1111110?

Comment: @Adam yes, from the definition of 2's complement

Comment: and if so then what would be the highest and lowest integer that can be represented by this 7 bit situation? would it be 2^7=64 and 2^0 which equals 1?

Comment: @Adam It would be $-2^6$ to $2^6 - 1$. I suggest reading about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement